# How to check if event already exists for marker in google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have created a marker and attached click event listener to the marker. However, I would like to check if the click event has been already attached to the marker and if not, attach the click event listener.

```
// If no click event listener, then attach the listener
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

I can however check with a custom flag in the marker object as:

```
// If no click event listener, then attach the listener
if (! marker._isClickEventBound) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    marker._isClickEventBound = true;
  });
}
```

The same code is executed during the addition of new marker and editing the marker. I just wanted to know if there is any other way rather than adding a flag ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a flag is actually fine.

Apart from that, `google.maps.event.addListener` returns you an event object. You can keep track of all event objects you've added to also clean up marker events if needed...

Answer (score 1):

hasListeners returns a boolean:

```
google.maps.event.hasListeners(marker,'click')
```

also works on the map itself:

```
google.maps.event.hasListeners(map,'idle')
```

Answer (score -1):

Ugly hack would be to remove all listeners and attach it one more time.

```
google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'click');
```